Is there a way to cancel future in Dart?
Is there a way to cancel future in Dart?
Is there an alternative to Future for this case?
We compute something but discard the result if a new request is made:
class A extend ChangeNotifier{
    int _token = 0;
    Data? _data = null;
    Data? get { return _data}
    void foo() {
        _token = _token + 1;
        var token = _token;
        var data = await ReallyLongCompute(); // the value will be discarded if the user click multiple time on the button
       if (_token == token)
           _data = data;
           notifyListener();
       } else {
           // discard the data computed for no reason
       }
}

void ButtonOnClick() {
    var a = Provider.of<A>();
    await a.foo()
}



CancelableOperation - the docs say: "An asynchronous operation that can be cancelled.
The value of this operation is exposed as value. When this operation is cancelled, value won't complete either successfully or with an error. If value has already completed, cancelling the operation does nothing."

@pskink from my own testing CancelableOperation doesn't stop ReallyLongCompute, it just discard the result if the operation was cancel. do you see the same behavior?
